# How to get cookies in getinitial props in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to get cookies in getInitialprops to fetch api from page in nextjs?

Comment: Can you share your code trying to do what you need so it can provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Next Cookies from npm. Here is link below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-cookies

To read all cookies you can use

```
const allCookies = cookies(ctx);
```

To read single cookies

```
const { myCookie } = cookies(ctx);
```

Example

```
import React from 'react'
import cookies from 'next-cookies'

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    return {
      initialName: cookies(ctx).name || ''
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: props.initialName || ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const newName = event.target.value;
    this.setState({name: newName});
    document.cookie = `name=${newName}; path=/`;
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({name: ''});
    document.cookie = 'name=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hi {this.state.name}</p>
        <p>Change cookie: <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your name here"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />!
        </p>
        <p>Delete cookie: <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm
```